# Set length of characters in input text

Tags: html

How do I set this input box to not be this long?

My code:

```
 <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputPassword">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pswrd']; ?>">
 </div>
```

The display:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74pyp.png)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/maxlength

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to put a text limit in a form input box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40271788/how-to-put-a-text-limit-in-a-form-input-box)

Answer (score 1):

Add `maxlength = "20"` inside `<input>` tag to make 20 characters the maximum length. Change as needed.

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['pswrd']; ?>" maxlength = "20" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as the other answer stated, you can use maxlength. If you want to validate the password (like what symbols should be included, minlength, etc) you can use javascript to achieve this. You can get more information on javascript validation here -
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_password_validation.asp

And I would also recommend that you revise your question, it lacks context and is not found helpful for others.